# Entry of Uninstaller from the Start Menu Shortcut is getting deleted after clicking on the finish button

Tags: install4j

I have an app which creates shortcuts for launcher and Uninstaller in the Start Menu. It works well on Windows 7 but when I installed the same app on Windows 10, it does creates the shortcuts for both in the Start Menu folder but the entry for Uninstaller is getting deleted just after clicking the finish button on the last installation screen. I think just after clicking the finish button some cleanup action starts as I see in the Installation log but don't know if this is clearing the Uninstaller entry in the Start Menu folder. I am using the 6.0.4 version of Install4j. Please advise how to resolve this.

The logs for creating the start menu shortcuts are below:

[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.desktop.CreateProgramGroupAction [ID 10]: Execute action
       Property unixMenuEntries: false
       Property uninstallerMenuName: MyApp Uninstaller
       Property categories: Application
       Property addUninstaller: true
       Property allUsers: true
       Property linkDirectory: 
       Property unixSymlinks: false
       Property programGroupName: MyApp_1.1
       Property addDefaultLauncherLinks: true

```
   Property programGroupEntryConfigs: [ProgramGroupFileConfig{target=MyApp.exe, arguments='', runAsAdministrator=false}]
   Property failForSymlinksNotCreated: false
   Property rollbackSupported: true
```

Install file: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApp_11.1\MyAppHelpViewer.lnk; size: 2149 bytes; exists: false
       File options set to: [fileTime: Wed Dec 30 07:50:39 EST 2015, mode: 644, overwriteMode: Always, shared: false, uninstallMode: Always, delayIfNecessary: false]

Install file: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApp_11.1\MyApp Uninstaller.lnk; size: 2142 bytes; exists: false
       File options set to: [fileTime: Wed Dec 30 07:50:39 EST 2015, mode: 644, overwriteMode: Always, shared: false, uninstallMode: Always, delayIfNecessary: false]

Install file: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApp_11.1\MyApp.lnk; size: 2129 bytes; exists: false
       File options set to: [fileTime: Wed Dec 30 07:50:40 EST 2015, mode: 644, overwriteMode: Always, shared: false, uninstallMode: Always, delayIfNecessary: false]
       Execute action successful after 610 ms

The entry for MyApp.exe and MyAppHelpViewer.exe remains there in the Start Menu folder but after clicking the finish button the entry for MyApp Uninstaller is getting disappeared.

The below log is printed for the clicking finish button:

```
   [INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FinishedScreen [ID 12]: Show screen
   [INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FinishedScreen [ID 12]: command: finish
   cleaning up
   Finished
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant section from the installation log?

Comment: The log has been appended in the description.

Comment: Please send the entire log file and the .install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem using NSIS Script. The short-cut for the Uninstaller in the start menu is there. Finishing the setup by clicking "Finish": the short-cut disappears... But its there in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\\. It is just not shown in the start menu.

Seems to be a Windows 10 "Feature". But I did not yet find out how it works.

Comment: This is the feature of Windows 10, if Uninstaller entry is required in Star Menu Shortcut then the name of the shortcut of installer has to changed.